# C++ constants initialization when one constant takes other constant value

Tags: c++, initialization, constants

I can't initialize constant in class where one constant depends on other constant value.

```
class foo {
private:
   const int secondConst;
   const int firstConst;
public:
   foo(int x) :
          firstConst(x),
          secondConst(firstConst*3)
   {
       // constructor code here....
   }
}
```

secondConst is a trash value,
how can I initialize it properly?
Maybe in C++ one constant can't rely on other constant during initialization time?

I edited my post. The problem really was that in original code I switched const fields where they were declared.

Comment: I think this should work, but as a workaround couldn't you just do: `foo(int x) : firstConst(x), secondConst(x*3)` ?

Comment: That should work; there must be something else going wrong. Could you post a [complete test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I avoid const members like this for a number of reasons. If you want a Foo object that doesn't change, make it const instead.

Comment: [It does work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0647410bbfc08826), please provide code that reproduces the behavior you mention in your question.

Comment: There's a sequence point in between each member initialization, so this code is correct. Are you sure your actual code has the members declared in initialization order like they are here, though? Members are initialized in the order they appear in the class declaration, not the order they appear in the initializer list.

Comment: My guess is that the particular compiler you're using doesn't think firstConst is initialized by the time secondConst's initializer is in place. There's something tickling the back of my memory that says that C++ doesn't guarantee the order of initialization, which may have something to do with this.

Comment: @JoeSewell: In C++ the construction order of members is guaranteed, though sometimes unintuitive.  The code as posted should be safe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your sample works for me. However if I change the order to have

```
private:
   const int secondConst;
   const int firstConst;
```

then `secondConst` gets garbage. The reason is that data members are initialized in the order they are declared, not in the order they appear in the member initialization list.

From the standard:

> Then, non-static data members are initialized in the order they were declared in the class definition
>   (again regardless of the order of the *mem-initializers*).

Comment: @user3528438 If the compiler supports it :).